# Как получить токен для запроса на сервер

Tags: python, requests

Пишу скрипт для работы с разными аккаунтами одного сайта. Для отправки запросов мне нужен токен доступа. Как его можно получить, если в распоряжении есть только логин и пароль? Использую Python 3.8, библиотека requests.

Comment: Токен есть в куки, но есть ли возможность его оттуда достать?

Answer (score 1):

Если токен есть в `cookies` получить его можно следующим образом

```
import requests

r = requests.get('http://example.com/some/cookie/setting/url')
    
for c in r.cookies:
    print(c.name, c.value)
```

При последующих запросах можете отправлять его следующим образом

```
import requests

cookies = {'session': 'cookies'}

r = requests.post('http://wikipedia.org', cookies=cookies)
```

Пример сохранения сессии между запросами

```
import requests
r1 = requests.post('http://example.com/login')
r2 = requests.post('http://example.com/admin',cookies=r1.cookies)
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: Я пишу этот скрипт для сайта с авторизацией. То есть, после авторизации пользователь делает некое действие, после которого отправляется запрос на сервер, а точнее на https://api.site.com/something. Вопрос: как мне достать куки именно авторизованного пользователя? У меня есть логин и пароль.